# difference between the Manage web controls in Web Recorder command and Object cloning object properties

Tags: automationanywhere

Please tell me the difference between the Manage web controls in Web Recorder command and Object cloning object properties.

I have searched a lot on the Web about it but found the difference between Web Recorder and Object Cloning but Web management Control and object cloning is same thing.I didn't find the difference between these two controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web Recorder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj-j21v8C_Q) has the capability to issue many [Object Cloning](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/enterprise/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/commands/object-cloning-command.html) commands when it executes. The latter is for a specific thing, like grabbing a control out of a web page.
But furthermore, Object Cloning isn't specific to a Web application, it could also apply to a desktop app, where it does things like interact with a menu.